# Halting problem for finitary PCF

Tags: computability, pl.programming-languages, semantics, undecidability

Is the halting problem decidable for finitary [PCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Computable_Functions)? By "halting problem" I mean the problem of deciding whether a closed PCF term evaluates to bottom under the denotational semantics of PCF. *Finitary* PCF is a version of PCF whose only base type is the type of booleans (so every type is finite).

Comment: What is finitary PCF? Please ask questions in a (mostly) self-contained way. There are experts here, but for the most part they are not mind readers.

Comment: For PCF you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Computable_Functions. Finitary PCF is a version of PCF whose only type has a finite number of values (for example, the Boolean type).

Comment: Please edit your question, not write more comments. And explain what "finitary" means, please. While you are at it, what is the halting problem for a programming language?

Comment: Sure, thanks! I am a newbie...

Comment: I fixed it up some more for you.

Comment: Are you aware of https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(00)00194-8?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the question. Yes, I am aware of Loader's paper. However, my understanding is that it answers a different question, namely the problem of deciding whether two finitary PCF terms are observationally equivalent.

Comment: Right, we can reduce $x = \bot$ to $x \leq \bot$, but it's not so clear how to reduce $x \leq y$ to $\bot$-testing.

Comment: My first instinct is to say that it's decidable, because we ought to be able to tell how many times we need to unfold a $\mathsf{fix} \, e$ by looking at the types of subexpressions of $e$. But these things can be tricky.